# Update of column value within a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

Before insert or update of any columns I want to update 1 system column with standard hash MD5 of all table columns, trigger is attached to. My intention is not to tailor this trigger with enumeration of all columns for each trigger and have a function that returns concatenated list of columns per table.

Table DDL:

```sql
create table TEST (
  id int,
  test varchar(100),
  "_HASH" varchar(32)
);
```

Here is my trigger DDL that I would love to work :

```plsql
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_SYS_HASH_BEFORE_INSERT_OR_UPDATE
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON TEST
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_columns VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
    var_columns := FUNC_LISTAGG_EXT(‘TEST');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT STANDARD_HASH(' || var_columns || ', ''MD5'') from dual'
        INTO :new."_HASH";
END;
```

However this is simply taking headers and set same hash for every row. If I should do this manually , trigger would look like this, what works as I desire, but create it for several tens of tables would be overwhelming

```plsql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_SYS_HASH_BEFORE_INSERT_OR_UPDATE
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON TEST
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_columns VARCHAR(10000);
BEGIN
    var_columns := FUNC_LISTAGG_EXT('TEST');
    SELECT STANDARD_HASH( :new."ID" || :new."TEST" , 'MD5' )
  INTO :new."_HASH";
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
```

So my question is whether solution is achievable

Note:
`FUNC_LISTAGG_EXT` function returns concatenated list of columns from system view

Comment: You'd need to reference the fields of the `:new` pseudo-record directly as your second trigger does.  You can't realistically do that dynamically.  You could write code that would dynamically generate the code for triggers on the "tens of tables" you want similar triggers to be defined on.  Of course, you'd then need to remember to re-run that generation logic whenever a column is added to one of those tables.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How to generate hashkey using multiple columns in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226040/1509264) or [PL/SQL Trigger - Dynamically reference :NEW or :OLD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687882/1509264)

Comment: "create it for several tens of tables would be overwhelming" Just create the trigger by hand for those tables; do not try to automate it as you will spend longer automating it (and it will be more likely to break) than if you just copy/paste and manually edit.

Comment: I dont think it is duplicate, since there is combination of several approaches. Gentlemen thanks for you notes, at least I will not waste more energy on this and will prepare generation that would work.